# Cabal Therapy trick in response to Shock

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Let's say my opponent plays a [Shock](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bShock%5d). In response,
can I cast [Cabal Therapy](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCabal%20Therapy%5d) to get rid of it?
As in [Counterspell](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCounterspell%5d) or such. Please give me the full ruling on this card

Answer (score 13):

That will not work. There are multiple issues with trying to do that.

First, once a player casts a spell, that spell is on the stack. Cards such as Counterspell and [Redirect](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bRedirect%5d) interact with spells on the stack. Cabal Therapy removes cards from an opponent's hand; it does not interact with the stack. So, if you were to cast Cabal Therapy in response to your opponent casting Shock and you name "Shock", you can make them discard every copy of Shock that is still in their hand, but it would have no effect on the Shock that they already cast.

Second, Cabal Therapy is a Sorcery. This means that in general, you cannot cast it in response to anything. There are some cards that change that, such as [Leyline of Anticipation](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bLeyline%20of%20Anticipation%5d) and [Vedalken Orrery](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bVedalken%20Orrery%5d).

Answer (score 4):

I think you only need the card text and an understanding of what it means to Cast a Spell: Cabal Therapy looks at the opponents hand, so if you cast CT *in response* to something like Shock, then the Shock has already been played so it is not in their hand anymore. Thus you can not counter a spell that has already been played by trying to remove it from their hand.

**Cabal Therapy:**

> Choose a nonland card name. Target player reveals his or her *hand* and
>   discards all cards with that name.
>   (It's also a Sorcery, so you can't respond to anything with it anyway)

**Casting Spells:**

> 601.2. To cast a spell is to take it from where it is (usually the hand), put it on the stack, and pay its costs, so that it will
>   eventually resolve and have its effect. ...